# Why does $_GET = index.php

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?ToDo=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When doing a print_r($_GET), it outputs

```
Array ( [ToDo] => index.php )
```

however, when I change the Rewrite Rule to

```
^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?ToDo=$1 [L,QSA]
```

print_r then outputs that $_GET is an empty array. Can someone explain to me why this occurs?

Comment: What URL is producing this output?

Comment: the full url is on my local server and outputs //local.test/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take an example URI `/abc`:

Your first regex:

```
^([^/]+)/?$
```

Matches `/abc` and rewrites it to:

```
/index.php?ToDo=abc
```

Now `mod_rewrite` engine runs again and matches the regex `^([^/]+)/?$` again for URI `/index.php` and rewrites it to:

```
/index.php?ToDo=index.php
```

Your 2nd regex:

```
^([^/.]+)/?$
```

works fine because it doesn't match `/index.php` URI.

Best way to write this rule is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?ToDo=$1 [L,QSA]
```

These two `RewriteCond` lines will prevent rewriting if request is for a valid file or directory.

Comment: Fantastic; Thanks, @Anubhava! I will accept this when the option is available. I appreciate the solution.

Comment: Well-explained, +1 :)